# Spring boot Many to one with non key join column not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a legacy database design with two entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblRouters")
public class Router implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "nRouterID")
    private Integer routerId;

    @Column(name = "strRouterName")
    private String routerName;

    @Column(name = "strRouterIP")
    private String routerIp;

    @Column(name = "strLastAutomaticCheckTime")
    private String lastCheckTime;

    @Column(name = "nSupportedSnmpVersion")
    private String protocol;

    @OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="strIpAddr", referencedColumnName="strRouterIP")
    //@JoinColumn(name="strIpAddr")
    private Set<RouterDetail> routerDetails;
cons, getters setters....
```

and the RouterDetail class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblRouter_Detail")
public class RouterDetail implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "nObjectId")
    private Integer objectId;

    @Column(name = "cObjectType")
    private Character objectType;

    @Column(name = "strSysName")
    private String systemName;

    @Column(name = "strDescription")
    private String systemDescription;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="strRouterIP")
    private Router router;
```

After some struggle i managed to create the correct mapping that allowed me to execute the query after using the referencedColumnName in the @JoinColumn in Router class, however i need the query to be fetch the data eagerly so I went and changed this (on the Router class)

```
@OneToMany()
```

to

```
@OneToMany(fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
```

this broke my code with the following exception

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid
>   column name 'strRouterIP'.

im using spring boot 1.5.3 with this interface to execute the query

```
public interface RouterService extends CrudRepository<Router, Integer> {

    public Iterable<Router> findAllByRouterDetailsObjectType(Character objectType);


}
```

What is wrong with this mapping?

Comment: Try to refer bean's parameter's names instead of actual column names. I mean to say change code like @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="strRouterIP")
    private Router router;  to @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="routerIp")
    private Router router;

Comment: @afridi thanks i tried to do as you suggest but i got "Invalid column name 'routerIp'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by modifying the RouterDetail join column to this

```
@JoinColumn(name ="strIpAddr", referencedColumnName="strRouterIP")
```